# Incorrect answer from Alexa

Tags: alexa, amazon-echo

I asked "Alexa, what's the distance between San Francisco and Los Angeles?". Alexa replied "11,711.8 kilometers away", which is absolutely incorrect.

Why does this happen? Am I missing something here? What can I do about such incidents?

Comment: Alexa likes to take the scenic route ... lol ... why are you expecting anyone to know what Alexa understood when you asked your question?

Comment: ask again ... if you still get an incorrect response, then ask for driving directions

Comment: For some reason it would appear that Alexa is trying to find the distance between you and either San Fransisco and Los Angeles... Perhaps Alexa is finding some place near you which is called Los Angeles or San Fransisco (like a restaurant or anything)?  Maybe try asking "what's the distance between San Fransisco California and Los Angeles California"?

Comment: Alexa, who won the recent US presidential election?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WA5Zhir8rbc

Comment: Awesome in that case I will post it as an answer to your question.  Glad it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason it would appear that Alexa is trying to find the distance between you and either San Fransisco and Los Angeles... Perhaps Alexa is finding some place near you which is called Los Angeles or San Fransisco (like a restaurant or anything)?

I would suggest asking "what's the distance between San Fransisco **California** and Los Angeles **California**"?

This should give Alexa the "hint" it needs to realise that you're not talking about something local.